# How to publish my joomla site on local server to the web?

Tags: networking, server, webserver

I am looking to access my Joomla site that I have on my Ubuntu server from outside my local network. I'm a new to this world of web publishing.

I know how to port forward with ex: No-Ip or Dyndns if I have the port number. But in this case I don't have a port number it just goes like this 192.168.x.xxx/joomla/

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no port number, it should be using the implied `:80` port. Try port forwarding port 80.

Comment: Wow thanks its somethig I should have known. It works! Now just a little html code and I'm live